# How to display an image in a selected radio label?

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, how can I show an image only in the selected radio label, and hide it when not selected? My example is using an image from a FA class, but I would like to be able to use an image from a URL also.

I'm sure this has been answered before so I'm probably searching for the wrong thing.

```css
.myButton{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.selected-image{
  float:right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.myButton i{
  float:right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.button-image{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myButton span{
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <label class="myButton">
      <input type="radio"  name="contact" value="email">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <!--<img class="selected-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/16">-->
      <img class="button-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/60">
      <span>Option 1</span>
    </label>

    <label class="myButton">
      <input type="radio"  name="contact" value="email">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <!--<img class="selected-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/16">-->
      <img class="button-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/60">
      <span>Option 2</span>
    </label>

    <label class="myButton">
      <input type="radio"  name="contact" value="email">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <!--<img class="selected-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/16">-->
      <img class="button-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/60">
      <span>Option 3</span>
    </label>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:checked` pseudo class selector with a `sibling` selector to display your image. Otherwise, it'll be hidden.

Here's an example using a general (`~`) sibling selector with opacity:

```css
.myButton{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.selected-image{
  float:right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.myButton i{
  float:right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.button-image{
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fas.fa-check {
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked ~ .fas.fa-check {
  opacity: 1;
}

input:checked ~ .button-image {
  opacity: 1;
}

.myButton span{
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <label class="myButton">
      <input type="radio"  name="contact" value="email">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <!--<img class="selected-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/16">-->
      <img class="button-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/60">
      <span>Option 1</span>
    </label>

    <label class="myButton">
      <input type="radio"  name="contact" value="email">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <!--<img class="selected-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/16">-->
      <img class="button-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/60">
      <span>Option 2</span>
    </label>

    <label class="myButton">
      <input type="radio"  name="contact" value="email">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <!--<img class="selected-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/16">-->
      <img class="button-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/60">
      <span>Option 3</span>
    </label>
  </body>
</html>
```

MDN References:

- [Pseudo Class Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)
- [General Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

Comment: is it also possible to style the labels border using input:checked?

Comment: @ddrjca - With the current mark up, unfortunately it wouldn't be. If you're free to modify the mark up, moving the radio out of the label would allow you to style the label based on whether the input is checked. You would also have to add a `for` attribute to click the radio. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/w74fkabd/